# API Logos Always Display Stack Overflow Logo

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, logo

No matter which API domain which is visited, the Stack Overflow logo is displayed instead of either 1) the site logo, or 2) the Stack Apps logo.

For example, http://api.serverfault.com/1.0/help does not use the Server Fault or Stack Apps logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the network logo here in this case, now completed!